# how do i reset particular fields from a row in table using php

Tags: php, mysql, reset

i have to reset columns of the particular field from the row in database. I am using MYSQL and in a database table i have given multiple fields like

```
1)  Sr. Number
2)  Serial Key
3)  Activation Date
4)  Valid From Date
5)  Valid Till Date
6)  Name
7)  Device ID
8)  Activity Count
```

i have made one form in which i am fetching the database entries. and after each entry i have given reset button, on the click of which i have to reset serial key and device id from database. I got one suggestion to take pointer to the Sr. number. but i am not getting any idea of resetting these two columns. in which 1 is at no.2 position and another is at no.7. Your suggestion will be needful and if any examples u know then please suggest.

```
echo "<table align='center' id='tbl' border='1' >"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>device_id</th><th>serialkey</th><th>firstname</th><th>created_on</th><th>keygenerated_on</th><th>modify_on</th><th>expiry_date</th><th>active</th><th>delete</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['device_id'] . "</td><td>" .$row['serialkey'] . "</td><td>" .$row['firstname'] . "</td><td>" .$row['created_on'] . "</td><td>" .$row['keygenerated_on'] . "</td><td>" .$row['modify_on'] . "</td><td>" .$row['expiry_date'] . "</td><td>" .$row['active'] . "</td><td><a href='display.php?del=0&id=".$row['id']."'>delete</a></td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
```

this is a sample code which i have used for delete. please suggest me for reset.

attached screenshot also

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate .... " but i am not getting any idea of resetting these two columns. in which 1 is at no.2 position and another is at no.7. "

Comment: ok... will share screenshot

Comment: @Bere $query = mysql_query("select * from tbluser");

Comment: @Kiren as u can see i have an entry in a table row. my question us instead of delete as u can see i have to give reset button. when i click on reset only device_id and suppose keygenerated on should get reset not the whole row entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your listing table (shown in the screen shot) instead of putting 'delete' link do

```
<a href="some_script.php?reset_id='".$row['id']."' "><button type="button">Reset</button></a>
```

In some_script.php

```
   <?php

    $reset_id=$_GET['reset_id']; //consider sanitizing the data

    $query="update <the_table_name> set `serial key` = NULL, `device id`= NULL where id = '".$reset_id."' "; //assuming reset mean setting to NULL. Replace <the_table_name> with the table name you are working with

    $con=mysqli_connect("yourhost","db_username","db_password","your_db_name");
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        //error
    }

//else you did it
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the values of device_id and serial_id in text fields. Then you can add a new 'reset' button that will reset the fields to the required values when clicked.

```
<td><input type='text' name='serialkey' value='$row[serialkey]'></td>
```